# Numpy: flatten multiple arrays of different shape from a dict

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dict containing np.array of different shapes:

```py
d = {
   "a" : np.array([1, 2, 3]), # shape (3,)
   "b" : np.array([4]), # shape (1,)
   "c" : np.array([[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]) # shape (2, 3)
}
```

Now I want to append them to form a vector, like this:

```py
output = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

How can I do that?

Comment: are you familiar with pandas?

Comment: @AnuragDabas yes, pandas will do too

Comment: How about `np.concatenate([arr.ravel() for arr in d.values()])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from pandas.core.common import flatten
```

**With pandas:**

```
array=np.array(list(flatten(d.values())))
```

**With numpy:**

```
array=np.hstack([arr.ravel() for arr in d.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Probably not the most efficient since `new_arr` changes shape on every iteration. You could probably iterate the dictionary once to determine the number of elements and create a new array with the correct size but that is more involved.

```
import numpy as np
d = {
   "a" : np.array([1, 2, 3]), # shape (3,)
   "b" : np.array([4]), # shape (1,)
   "c" : np.array([[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]) # shape (2, 3)
}
# %%
new_arr = np.array([])
for arr in d.values():
    new_arr = np.append(new_arr, arr.flatten(),axis=0)
```